# って as a particle?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, particle-って

It's as simple as that. Can って be used as a particle, and if so, what does it imply? I saw it in this phrase:
"……ねえお母さん。
僕って、みんなと違うのかな？"

Comment: We even have a [**particle-って** question tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6), which I've just added to your post. 

Comment: I suggest you to search a bit on this site or on Google. The answer would be "yes", but there are other uses as well. The first result on Google https://wildnihongo.com/grammar/tte-colloquial-topic-marker/